# Programmatic form dojo -- example?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I am new to dojo.. can anyone give me a reference of how to build a form in dojo programmatically which should contain label and a textarea

Thanks in advance

Comment: got it  http://jsfiddle.net/user_13g/gask3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it..have a look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/user_13g/gask3

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to get a copy of the Dojo API so you can view it, but usually any dojo form follows this format:

```
var foo = new dijit.form.xxx(/* Object */ params,
                             /* DomNode?|String? */ srcNodeRef);
```

For example:

```
foo = new dijit.form.Textarea({text: 'this is a text'}, "textnode");
foo.startup();
```